# Add Additional Fee to shipping methods for specific products

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, shipping-methods

what is the best approach to add Additional Fees to shipping methods for specific products

Comment: Can you describe it littel bit more?

Comment: yes sure. so I need to add some fee to the shipping methods for some specific products. my idea was to create an attribute for these products then check if the cart contain those product if true add some amount to the shipping methods. but I don’t know how can I add this fee to the shipping methods. do you have any idea ? thank you.

Comment: So you want to apply some extra charge on order based on the product right?

Comment: yes right , I want to create product attribute for example  I call it "require_extra_fee"  then check if product is in cart apply some extra charge for each shipping method.